# How do I export a 'database' from Oracle 11g XE and import it to Oracle 10.2?

Tags: windows, oracle11g, oracle10g

Up to this point, I've never done anything serious with an Oracle database. I know that they are different than what I've handled, like MS SQL.

So, coming from an MS SQL perspective, I can backup a database, copy over the .bak file to another server, restore it, creating a complete copy of the database.

I'm not sure how to do the same for Oracle, much less different versions. I've seen it done mostly with command lines, so I tried this:

```
$exp owner/owner schemas=tkcsdb directory=dumpdir dumpfile=dBaseName logfile=dBaseLog
```

And then the SQL Plus returns:

> Unknown Parameter Name 'Schemas'.
>   Failed to process parameters.
>   Export terminated unsuccessfully.

I've since replaced the 'schemas' with 'schema' (same error), and I wanted to try using 'tables', though I'm not sure how that would turn out. I'm not even 100% if 'tkcsdb' is the name of the *database* I'm looking for - I've been unable to list all the *databases* I have.

What I want to do (which I've done with MS SQL, MySQL, and even IBM DB2 of all things) is looking to be quite difficult to replicate in Oracle.

As with the title, how do I export a 'database' from Oracle 11g XE and import it to Oracle 10.2?

I'm using Windows 7, the target machine is a Linux Fedora of some sort.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

EXP and IMP are ancient - do not use them unless you absolutely have to. They cannot handle some of the features of newer Oracle versions.

The tools of choice are EXPDP and IMPDP (short for EXP datapump and IMP datapump).

Unfortunately, using them is a little more complicated, because you can run them only on the database server (contrary to old-style EXP/IMP, which you could run from any client computer).

So, to get your schema from the 11g source DB to the 10g target DB, you'll have to:

- open a terminal session on the 11g DB server
- run expdp with version set to 10 (so you can import it on the 10g server)
- copy the dump file fom the 11g server to the datapump directory of the 10g server (look for a directory called "dpump")
- open a terminal session on the 10g DB server
- run impdp with your dump file

Example:

```
expdp scott/tiger@db11g version=10.2 schemas=SCOTT dumpfile=SCOTT.dmp logfile=expdpSCOTT.log

impdp scott/tiger@db10g schemas=SCOTT dumpfile=SCOTT.dmp logfile=impdpSCOTT.log
```

Comment: I tried it with 'tkcsdb' as the schemas, convinced it was the name of the 'database'. It didn't work. Looking at your example, you put 'scott' in there as well. So I put in 'tkcsowner'. What do you call scott / tkcsowner, and how would you compare them to terminologies in, say, MS SQL? In any case, that did it. Thanks. It did return an error, though: "Password will expire in 7 days." Is this something I should be concerned about? Also, since there isn't a directory, where would the database dump the .dmp file?

Comment: Scott or tkcsowner are database "users". Each database user has his own "schema", where the objects of this user "live" (the terms user and schema are more or less synonyms in Oracle terminology). You should indeed be concerned about the password expiration error - just change the password (you could also change the profile associated with this user so the password never expires). The database will put the dump file in the datapump directory (unless you specify one with the directory parameter, but for starters, I'd recommend sticking to the default datapump dir).

Comment: tkcsowner/tkcsowner@db11g. I forgot to add the db11g. Strange thing is, it continued with the backup just fine. However, when I did it again with the db11g, it returns an error: Could not resolve the connect identifier specified.

Comment: Please post a new question if you encounter a new problem.